# Values selected but it doesnt appear in the input

Tags: angularjs, select, coffeescript

I have a problem with select2. I have selected values but it doesnt appear in the input when I reload the page. I think the problem is life cycle of the scope.

[image]

My code is the next:

```
<select style="width:100%"
    class="configServices"
    ng-options="service.service_code as service.service_name group by service.parent for service in services"
    multiple="true"
    ng-model="widget.configuration.services">
```

My cofeescript:

```
.directive 'selectServicesDirective', ['Services', '$translate', 'highchartsConfig',
  (Services) ->
restrict: 'ACE'
templateUrl: '/widgets/request-and-status/configuration/select-services.tpl.html'
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  scope.services = []
  scope.images = []
  scope.load = []
  scope.parent = []

  Services.status2 (services) ->
    services.data.forEach (service) ->
      if service.children
        service.children.forEach (children) ->
          scope.services.push {'service_name': children.service_name, 'service_code': children.service_code, 'parent': service.service_name}
          scope.images[children.service_name] = children.service_icon
      else
        scope.services.push {'service_name': service.service_name, 'service_code': service.service_code}
        scope.images[service.service_name] = service.service_icon

  scope.getParent = (serviceId) ->
    scope.parent.forEach (parent) ->
      if parent.id is serviceId
        console.log 'parent', parent.id
        return parent.id

  formatService = (service) ->
    return  $('<img style="height: 20px; width: 20px; border-radius:19px;" src="' +scope.images[service.text]+ '" /><b>'+' '+service.text+'</b>')

  $(".configServices").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 15,
    templateResult: formatService,
    templateSelection: formatService
  });

]
```

If I put

```
 $(".configServices").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 15,
    templateResult: formatService,
    templateSelection: formatService
  }).val('3').change();
```

I can see the values selected in the input but it return an error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Answer (score 0):

> I have selected values but it doesnt appear in the input when I reload the page.

The page state will be reset when you reload the page. If you want to preserve state inbetween page loads you either need to store that state in cache, local storage or on server side.